# I don't understand the operation here: for index, item in enumerate(choices):

Tags: python, list, for-loop, enumerate

I'm currently learning Python through Codecademy. One of the exercises uses this in it's for loop:

```
choices = ['pizza', 'pasta', 'salad', 'nachos']

print 'Your choices are:'
for index, item in enumerate(choices):
    print index + 1, item
```

I've only seen things like:

```
for i in list:
```

That being said, I don't understand what the "index," part of the loop is, or what it's function is. All I understand from this is that it will index each item in the list, and print them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the docs on [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

Comment: `pizza index 0`, `pasta index 1` etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerate makes a `list` of `tuple` which are `(index, element)`.

```
l = ['thing', 'foo', 'bar', 'doodad']
list(enumerate(l))
```

This is the output of `enumerate`

```
[(0, 'thing'), (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'doodad')]
```

You can `unpack` these tuples and do whatever you'd like with each component of the tuple.

```
for index, element in enumerate(l):
    print 'index', index
    print 'element', element

index 0
element thing

index 1
element foo

index 2
element bar

index 3
element doodad
```

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate` returns both the index of the item in the list, and the item itself. Each item in a Python list (and almost any list in any programming language) has a numeric index in addition to the value it contains. In Python, indexes start at 0. So for your `choices` list, `pizza` has the index `0`, `pasta` has `1`, `salad` has `2`, and `nachos` has `3`. This index exists to allow you direct access to the nth value of a list, without having to loop through it (among other uses).

Here's what your code does when executed:

```
Your choices are:
1 pizza    # Pizza has index 0, and you added 1
2 pasta    # Index 1
3 salad    # Index 2
4 nachos   # Index 3
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` adds an index or position value to each item in the list starting at 0.

so in your example `pizza` would have an index of 0, `pasta` has an index of 1 and so on...

Then your `for` syntax is slightly different to get both the index and value of the current item.

So first time through the loop you will have `index = 0` and `item = 'pizza'`

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the `enumerate` built-in function as described in the documentation for enumerate: [python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), [python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). I think the documentation describes it very clearly so would recommend reading there.